# array undefined variables when trying to retrieve imap results

Tags: php, codeigniter, imap

So I have a function that connects to my imap mailbox and gets the emails from it.

```
public function inbox() {
    $this->msg_cnt = imap_num_msg($this->conn);

    $in = array();

    for($i = 1; $i <= $this->msg_cnt; $i++) {
        $in = array(
            'index'     =>  $i,
            'header'    =>  imap_headerinfo($this->conn, $i),
            'body'      =>  imap_body($this->conn, $i),
            'structure' =>  imap_fetchstructure($this->conn, $i)
        );
    }

    $this->inbox = $in;

    return $this->inbox;
}
```

I am using codeigniter so the above is in a library and in my controller I have the following:

```
$this->load->library('Email_reader');
$data['emails'] = $this->email_reader->inbox();
```

And then in my view I have the following, which is where I am having issues at:

```
<?php foreach($emails as $email): ?>
   <?php echo $email->index.'<br/>'; ?>
<?php endforeach; ?>

<div class="well">
   <?php var_dump($emails); ?>
</div>
```

I am just trying to get all the variables to display nicely. But when I run it all, I get that I am trying to get a property of a non object or that `index` is not defined. from the foreach the errors come from the `<?php echo ... ?>`

The var dump displays just like it is supposed to with no errors.

The exact errors I am receiving are displayed in the screenshot below: What the heck am I doing wrong? Why is this not working?

[image]

Comment: In your for loop in the inbox function I think you want $in[] = not just $in =

Comment: Looks like you are returning an array, but you try to handle it as an Std:Class. var_dump($email) to see whats going on.

Comment: @xd6_ That was the problem. Wow I'm an idiot.

Comment: Now, I've got my subjects all echoed out some of them have weird things around them like this one: `=?utf-8?Q?Test_Email?=` should just be `Test Email` others display just fine though??